# Delete data using javascript __dopostback

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

I have a problem in my laravel project.
When I load coupon with curl...

[image: this is the coupon]

Sometimes I need to delete matches from the coupon. I have the button but it's not working.

This is the button

[image]

this is the blade of coupon

```
 <div class="Top">
    <h3>Bulletin</h3>
    <span></span>


</div>

<div class="Cnt" id="divContentCoupon">
    <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidRiserva"
           id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_hidRiserva" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidAttesa"
           id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_hidAttesa" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidCouponAsincrono"
           id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_hidCouponAsincrono" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidIsTemporaryCoupon"
           id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_hidIsTemporaryCoupon">
    <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidTipoCoupon"
           id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_hidTipoCoupon">
    <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidStatoCoupon"
           id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_hidStatoCoupon" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidBonusNumScommesse"
           id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_hidBonusNumScommesse">
    <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidQuotaTotaleDIMax"
           id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_hidQuotaTotaleDIMax">
    <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidQuotaTotaleDIMin"
           id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_hidQuotaTotaleDIMin">
    <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidQuotaTotale"
           id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_hidQuotaTotale">
    <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidIDQuote"
           id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_hidIDQuote">
    <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidModificatoQuote"
           id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_hidModificatoQuote" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidBonusQuotaMinimaAttivo"
           id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_hidBonusQuotaMinimaAttivo" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidBonusRaggruppamentoMinimo"
           id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_hidBonusRaggruppamentoMinimo" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidNumItemCoupon"
           id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_hidNumItemCoupon" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidIDCoupon"
           id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_hidIDCoupon">
    <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$hidPrintAsincronoDisabled"
           id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_hidPrintAsincronoDisabled" value="0">

    <div id="divAttesa" style="display:none" class="cpnDivAttesa">

        <div class="spinningloader"></div>
        <div class="divAnimazioneLiveHTML"></div>
        <div id="countdowntimer" class="cpn"></div>

    </div>

    <div id="divCouponAsync" style="display:none;" class="divCouponAsync">
        Pari accepté avec réserve, vérifiez le résultat dans votre liste paris.
        <div><input type="submit" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$btnScoAncoraAsync"
                    value="Parier encore (+)" onclick="NewBet();"
                    id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_btnScoAncoraAsync" class="button"
                    onkeyup="trapNextBet(event, &#39;h_w_PC_cCoupon_btnScoAncoraAsync&#39;);return false;"
                    style="width:150px;"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="divInserimentoScommesse">
        <!-- **0** COUPON VUOTO-->
        <div id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_divCouponVuoto" class="couponempty"
             onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, &#39;h_w_PC_cCoupon_btnFakeLoad&#39;)">

            Cliquez sur les côtes afin de les ajouter sur le coupon
            ou entrez un code à charger
            <div class="CpnPuls">
                <input name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtCouponCodiceAnonimo" type="text"
                       maxlength="5" id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_txtCouponCodiceAnonimo"
                       class="TxtBox" size="5"
                       onkeypress="LoadButtonEnter(&#39;h_w_PC_cCoupon_btnFakeLoad&#39;, event)">
                <a id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_lnkCaricaCouponCodiceAnonimo"
                   title="Charge les cotes et la mise en utilisant le code du pari que vous avez enregistré précédemment."
                   class="btnCoupon mx"
                   onclick="return load_coupp()">
                    <img id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_imgLoad" class="imgButtonCoupon"
                         src="/assets/img/load.png"
                         style="border-width:0px;">
                    CHARGER
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!--SEZIONE ERRORE GENERICO-->



        <!-- Inserimento asincrono di una quota -->
        <input type="button" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$btnAddCoupon" value="Add"
               onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;h$w$PC$cCoupon$btnAddCoupon&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"
               id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_btnAddCoupon" style="display:none;">
        <input type="button" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$btnAddQuota" value="Add"
               onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;h$w$PC$cCoupon$btnAddQuota&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"
               id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_btnAddQuota" style="display:none;">
        <input type="button" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$btnAddMultiIDQuota"
               value="Add"
               onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;h$w$PC$cCoupon$btnAddMultiIDQuota&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"
               id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_btnAddMultiIDQuota" style="display:none;">
        <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtIDQuota"
               id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_txtIDQuota">
        <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtSottoEventName"
               id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_txtSottoEventName">
        <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtQuota"
               id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_txtQuota">
        <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtCodPubblicazione"
               id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_txtCodPubblicazione">
        <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtIDEvento"
               id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_txtIDEvento">
        <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtEventName"
               id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_txtEventName">
        <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtIDSottoEvento"
               id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_txtIDSottoEvento">
        <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtGiocabilita"
               id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_txtGiocabilita">
        <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtTipoQuota"
               id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_txtTipoQuota">
        <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtIDTipoEvento"
               id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_txtIDTipoEvento">
        <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtIDTipoQuota"
               id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_txtIDTipoQuota">
        <input type="button" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$btnAddCouponQB" value="AddQB"
               onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;h$w$PC$cCoupon$btnAddCouponQB&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"
               id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_btnAddCouponQB" style="display:none">
        <input type="button" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$btnRefreshAttesa" value=""
               onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;h$w$PC$cCoupon$btnRefreshAttesa&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"
               id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_btnRefreshAttesa" style="display:none">
        <input type="button" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$btnRefreshAsincrono" value=""
               onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;h$w$PC$cCoupon$btnRefreshAsincrono&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"
               id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_btnRefreshAsincrono" style="display:none">
        <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtQB"
               id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_txtQB">
        <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtAddImporto"
               id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_txtAddImporto">

        <!-- Inserimento asincrono di un Coupon precompilato -->
        <input type="button" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$btnAddCouponPrecompilato"
               value=""
               onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;h$w$PC$cCoupon$btnAddCouponPrecompilato&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"
               id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_btnAddCouponPrecompilato"
               style="display:none">
        <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtIDCouponPrecompilato"
               id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_txtIDCouponPrecompilato">
        <input type="hidden" name="h$w$PC$cCoupon$txtImportoCouponPrecompilato"
               id="h_w_PC_cCoupon_txtImportoCouponPrecompilato">
    </div>
    <!--RICARICA COUPON-->

</div>
<div class="Btm"></div>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting exactly?

Comment: when i click button delete it's not work sir

Comment: I think this is because encoding issues in the code, for example: 

    __doPostBack(&#39;h$w$PC$cCoupon$btnAddMultiIDQuota&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"

do you have a control or event on the backend called "&#39;h$w$PC$cCoupon$btnAddMultiIDQuota&#39;,&#39;&#39;" ?

Comment: @NeriBarakat there is no event or function called like this sir .... do u know a function do like this